# How to calculate text location x with processing.org?

Tags: java, text, size, processing

I am having a hard time understanding how to calculate the size of a word in processing when there are different font sizes.

All I am trying to do is to put suffix right after the word "Metric". [image]

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

//code

```
PFont f;
PFont f2;
void setup(){
  size(600, 300);

  f = createFont("SegoeUI-Semibold-200", 100);
  f2 = createFont("SegoeUI-Semibold-200", 20);

}

String metric = "Metric";

void draw(){ 

float sw = textWidth(metric); //how can I use sw?
fill(240);
textFont(f);
text(metric, 0, height-20);

fill(0);
textFont(f2);
text("sufix",300, height-20); //How can I calculate x to be at then of word Metric

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

textWidth() will consider last call to font() or fontSize() to calc width, so you better use it after the proper call to fontSize, or font(font, size) or font(). IN your case it was considering the last font declared, the little one... Also, I called background() in draw, so words will not be constantly wrote over itself, what will prevent it to look bad.

```
PFont f;
PFont f2;
void setup(){
  size(600, 300);

  f = createFont("SegoeUI-Semibold-200", 100);
  f2 = createFont("SegoeUI-Semibold-200", 20);

}

String metric = "anystuff";

void draw(){ 
  background(110);


fill(240);
textFont(f);
text(metric, 0, height-20);
float sw = textWidth(metric); //after font is set...

fill(0);
textFont(f2);
text("sufix",sw, height-20); //just use it :)

}
```